# Redirecting after login and registration ONLY IF coming from a product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a digital download site running on WordPress/WooCommerce that requires users to be logged in to buy products. There is a login/register button displayed for logged-out users instead of the ‘Buy’ button on product pages as seen here: https://prnt.sc/1rc03lw. I’m trying to redirect users after they’ve logged in or registered back to the previous page but only if that previous page was a product page.

Here is the code I'm currently using which saves the referring URL and then executes a redirect. The redirect works but, I'm trying to limit it to only redirect if the referer URL was a product page (domain.com/product):

[CODE REDACTED]

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks, /JJ

**SOLUTION**

Thanks for all the responses! This is what we ended up with:

[CODE REDACTED]

Massive thanks to Idan for helping me out in the WooCommerce Developer Slack channel!

**CLEANER SOLUTION WITH REGISTRATION FORM REDIRECT FUNCTIONALITY**

I was receiving some critical errors - Idan helped me create a cleaner script and implemented the registration form actions too!

```
// Hide Add to Cart for logged out users
add_action( 'init', 'creatorcabin_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in' );
function creatorcabin_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in() {   
   if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {      
      remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
}

// Add Login to Buy button for logged out users
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'creatorcabin_user_logged_out_disable_add_to_cart', 30 );
function creatorcabin_user_logged_out_disable_add_to_cart() {
   if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {  
    $parameter = (is_singular("product")) ? '?product_page=1&my_page_id=' . get_the_ID() : '';
    echo '<div class="login-to-buy-box"><h4 style="color: #E67E22;">Login to buy!</h4><p style="color: black;">Login or Sign Up for free to unlock the buy button and gain access to your downloads! <a href="/learn/using-our-website/why-do-i-need-an-account-to-buy-stuff/" target="_blank><p style="font-style: italic;">Why do I need an account to buy stuff?</p></a><a href="/my-account' . $parameter . '"><div class="user-bought-singleproduct">Login / Register ></div></a></div>';
    }
}

// Referer
add_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_end', 'creatorcabin_actual_referer' );
function creatorcabin_actual_referer() {
   $product_page = (isset($_GET['product_page'])) ? $_GET['product_page'] : 0;
   $page_id = (isset($_GET['my_page_id'])) ? $_GET['my_page_id'] : 0;
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_page" value="' . $product_page . '" /><input type="hidden" name="my_page_id" value="' . $page_id . '" />';
}

//Login redirect
function custom_login_redirect($redirect) {
    if (isset($_POST['my_page_id']) && isset($_POST['product_page']) && intval($_POST['product_page']) === 1) {
        $redirect = get_permalink($_POST['my_page_id']);
    }
    return $redirect;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'custom_login_redirect', 10, 1);


// Action and Filter for Registration form
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end', 'creatorcabin_actual_referer' );
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'custom_login_redirect', 10, 1);
```

Again, massive thanks to Idan for helping me out in the WooCommerce Developer/Community Slack channel!

Comment: Let me translate that in simpler terms. You have a login form on each product page, if someone use that form, you want him to be redirected to the same initial product page? Let me know if I got it

Comment: Hey @amarinediary - yeah, apart from it isn't a form per say! It's just a button that takes you to the 'my-account' page to log in or register!

Comment: Yeah so the approach from WdeVlam should be the one. In short, you add a url parameter to your link (the one redirecting from the product page to login form). eg: `domain.com/path/to/login?redirect=true`. Then you just specify that if that url parameter is in the referer url, you redirect to the referer, else you redirect to the home page or something else.

Comment: Sorry if I've misunderstood this but, shouldn't the script be checking the referrer URL for something in the product page URL not, the login URL?

So, to type it out in plain text:

`If the referring URL contains domain.com/product/... redirect back to that page after login or registration`

`If not, continue to domain.com/my-account`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you just add a query arg to the link on product pages?

edit:
okay, so without going into too much detail as I'm tired and somewhat inebriated and can't be trusted around semicolons right now:

I would use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_url/ to set up the hrefs for my login links. You'll notice that the function comes with:
a: an optional argument for passing the url that the user should be referred to after login
and b: a filter hook called 'login_url' that you can use to hijack the process and apply your own logic in.

also wordpress comes with a function conveniently called 'add_query_arg' which does exactly what it says on the tin. (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/)

so if i were to set up some php that would return that string on a product page I'd do something like this:

```
$refer_to_url = get_permalink(get_the_ID()); //get current post/page permalink
$refer_to_url = add_query_arg('is_product_page', true, $refer_to_url); //add arguments to that url.
$this_login_url = wp_login_url($refer_to_url);
```

then I'd probably try and set up a filter that would change the referring url to e.g. the user's account page if is_product_page is not true.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/

you may also have to register the queryvar using

```
add_filter( 'query_vars',  function ( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'is_product_page';          
    return $qvars;
});
```

otherwise wordpress might refuse to process the query var.

hope that helps.

Comment: Could you please give me an example (new, learning coder here)? :)

Comment: This should be a comment. Tho indeed the approach would be far simpler.

Comment: @amarinediary probably right. still trying to get the hang of this.

Comment: Thanks for this! How would you use the WooCommerce login page (domain.com/my-account) instead of the wp-login page?

Comment: you could build the url string using home_url("/path_to_a_thing/my-account"); *but* this will bite you in the rear later on as users need to reset their passwords after they've forgotten them anyway and follow account activation links and so on. Unless you hook into the wordpress functions for that too they'll wind up at the wordpress login screen anyway. 

I used the hooks mentioned here to build my own page for all that: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-wordpress-user-flow-part-1-replace-the-login-page--cms-23627

I'm sure there are also existing plugins. good luck!

Comment: Thanks, @WdeVlam for pointing me in the right direction! I had some help from the WooCommerce developers Slack (specifically Idan who was an absolute legend in helping me write out the scripts and debug issues).

I've popped the scripts in the original post! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check on wp or template_redirect hook is previous page is shop page or not. I have assume and suggest code.

redirect after login will redirect and second function will check is request uri contains shop or not.

```
<?php

// Function to redirect after login (best so far)
function redirect_after_login(){
  global $wp;
 
      if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_home() && ($wp->query_vars['pagename'] != 'downloads') ){
        $redirect = home_url() . "/wp/wp-login.php?redirect_to= $protocol://" . 
        $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);


        $shop_url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        $shop_end = "/shop/";

        if (!endsWith($shop_url, $shop_end)) {

            wp_redirect( $redirect );
            exit;
        }
     }

}
add_action( 'wp', 'redirect_after_login', 3 );

// Check is previous page requst url shop page

function isCheckShop($haystack, $needle) {
    $length = strlen($needle);
    if ($length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return (substr($haystack, -$length) === $needle);
}
```

Comment: This looks great, thank you! Will this work if the URL is not /shop? Although the main shop page is domain.com/shop, the individual product pages where the login/register buttons are located are domain.com/product/product-name!

Comment: There is also an unclosed '{' on line 2. Where should this be closed? :)

Comment: I have added condition you need to check.

Comment: I activated this script and got the following error when trying to access the site, "There has been a critical error on this website" :(

Comment: Just fixed code

Comment: Let's give it a go! :)

Comment: Same error: "There has been a critical error on this website." :(

Comment: $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; what you get here?

Comment: Ah, no! Just when I visit any page on the website. I get "There has been a critical error on this website"!

Answer (score 0):

Actually,

The `wp_login_url()` function let you specify a redirect variable through `$redirect`.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_url/

```
<?php 

// for the sake of the argument... 
$current_url = home_url( '/product/spiderman-toy-statue-red' );

// in live environment you could use something like this... 
// global $wp;
// $current_url = home_url( add_query_arg( $_GET, $wp->request ) );

echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_login_url( $current_url )  ) . '">Login redirect example</a>';
```

Your user would click that link on a product page and after login be redirected to that page.

Comment: This looks good! I've implemented this into my product page login/register button as you can see here:

`<a href="' . esc_url( wp_login_url( $current_url )  ) . '"<div class="user-bought-singleproduct">Login / Register ></div></a></div>';`

but, this takes the user to the wp-login page. Is it possible to take them to the 'my-account page (WooCommerce)? This page is styled for front-end users. I haven't been able to test the redirect because once you login through wp-login, it takes you to the WordPress Dashboard (wp-admin)!